# Strategy to delete data from some columns in a large SQL table temporarily and revert them back later on

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 60 columns on a SQL Server. I have to remove data from 10-15 columns temporarily for a date range not for whole table so that I can execute some report queries and then execute another report query after few days with deleted data reverted back into columns. 
Following tables illustrates what I am trying to achieve.

Table A

```
|1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |....|55|56|57|58|59|60|
---------------------------------------
|1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |....| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6|
|1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |....| 7| 8| 9|10|11|12|
```

Delete data from columns 55 - 60 and execute report on below table.

Table B

```
|1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |....|55|56|57|58|59|60|
---------------------------------------
|1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |....|0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |
|1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |....| 7| 8| 9|10|11|12|
```

After few days revert deleted data back to Table A and execute another query.

The problem here is that table A's size is around 50gb and I have to remove data from columns on a record of 10 to 100 thousand.

I have tried to select columns to be removed into temporary table and updated column data with 0s. After few days moved them back with update statement however this works ok with single user. When there are multiple users running report queries this strategy causes some performance issues as queries takes longer because of updates.

Is there any other strategy that can be used in this case? I would like to hear your experience and suggestions please.

Note: I don't want to exclude selected columns from the query. Just want to delete some portion of the selected column's data based on date range but for other dates we take them into account as I am summing all columns.

Comment: Use a view.  Why does the reporting software have to directly reference the table?

Comment: I need to delete data from columns for a date range not for whole table columns. may be I need to add this in the problem description.

Comment: As Gordon says, shape the data for the report, don't change the data, thats risky, bad and terrible for performance.

Comment: Or a stored procedure as an alternative to a view.

Comment: rename the columns, create new columns with original name, copy data back based on your conditions.

Comment: Surely having a view simplifies your problem because you can create one view per client without having to mess with the original data.

Comment: If it really is impossible to shape the data to solve your problem consider creating another table specifically for reporting on which you copy the data required for the report into. That way you're not messing with live data.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a view and use that for the reporting:

```
create view v_t
    select col1, col2, . . .
           (case when <condition> then 0 else col55 end) as col55,
           (case when <condition> then 0 else col56 end) as col56,
           (case when <condition> then 0 else col57 end) as col57,
           (case when <condition> then 0 else col58 end) as col58,
           (case when <condition> then 0 else col59 end) as col59,
           (case when <condition> then 0 else col60 end) as col60
    from t;
```

I don't fully understand the condition, but it would seem to involve one or more date columns.

Use the view for the report.

Comment: Creating view would complicate things as I have many clients each having different column data removal configuration.

Comment: @user1534115 Sounds more like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You temporarily "hide" the actual values for a period of time for some report - but what about everything else that uses the table? Flipping a synonym might be an option but it sounds like you don't want to change your existing design. No easy solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the values temporarily, moving it to other table for some days and refilling the values again to that table, you shall inject that logic in to your report query itself by adding date range in the CASE statement. Say if you want to get the result of column 55 as 0 for the date range '2018-12-01' to '2009-12-31' then use the following query

```
SELECT 1,2,3,4,5.., 
    CASE 
       WHEN CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2009-12-31' then 0 else 55 
       END As 55
FROM [tablename];
```

Comment: seems like I have to update the description again as everybody thinks i want to remove all data from selected columns. i want to delete some portion of the selected data not all columns so removing columns from query by view is not an option

Answer (score 0):

As has been commented upon before, the most elegant solutions to your problem would involve using a separate construct such as:
 - Creating a view
 - Using a stored procedure
 - Adding filtering within the report itself

To these options I would like to add that you can use security to limit the columns that a user can access.  In this case you could limit the access that the user running the report has to the table.  See the below article for some more details on how you could go about doing this:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2124/filtering-sql-server-columns-using-column-level-permissions/